# Handle Angular html conflicts error

Tags: angular

In Angular 4, if I go to FirstComponent for example, and get any error like this one: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

You can still navigate in your website, but if route to SecondComponent, the HTML Dom mixed up and get some conflict so I see the content of FirstComponent (HTML Content) in SecondComponent.

Is there any way to handle any error and avoid this mixed up issue?

Comment: Please show some example code

Comment: @Daniel the problem is not in specific code dear, suppose you are reading from API, and you have typos in "page" word for example and you write it "pafe", you will got undefined property error, and when you route to another component, the DOM issue appeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular blocks component rendering if it encounters an exception. This is the design of the default error handler. If you want to change this, you will have to build your own error handler (check out [Angular.io](https://angular.io/api/core/ErrorHandler)).

Basicly you have to create a class that implements the `ErrorHandler` interface (from `@angular/core`), and then add it to your @NgModule as a provider.

#### Example (from Angular.io):

```
class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  handleError(error) {
    // do something with the exception
  }
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: MyErrorHandler}]
})
class MyModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel already said, this is the default behavior when Angular encounters an error in your template.

I would simply add that the type of error you're describing like

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

is a development error. It's not something your user is suppose to encounter at any time in production. It can be avoided easily by giving default values (like an empty array) to your properties, or properly check them before trying to display infos.

Hope that helps